# Why can't I access a property of this destinationViewController that conforms to a protocol?

Tags: swift, segue, protocols

I'm trying to pass an `NSManagedObjectContext` from one view controller to the next in my `prepareForSegue` method but I can't access the property I've created for it in the `destinationViewController`:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let identifier = segue.identifier {
      switch identifier {
      case "segueToSettings", "pickLiftSegue":
        if let nav = segue.destinationViewController as? UINavigationController {
          let vc = nav.topViewController as! Dismissable
          vc.dismissalDelegate = self

          let context = viewModel.model.context
          vc.moc = context // <-- Value of type Dismissable has no member `moc`
        }
      case "segueToLog":
        let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? Dismissable

        destinationVC?.dismissalDelegate = self
      default:
        break
      }
    }
  }
```

And here's the relevant part of the `destinationViewController`:

```
class SettingsViewController: UITableViewController, Dismissable, DismissalDelegateProtocol {

    @IBOutlet weak var forumlasTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var liftsTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var weightUnitControl: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var roundNumbersSwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var currentFormulaSelection: UITableViewCell!
    @IBOutlet weak var currentLiftsSelection: UITableViewCell!

    var dismissalDelegate: DismissalDelegateProtocol?
    var moc: NSManagedObjectContext? = nil // <-- There it is right there
}
```

I'm getting the error you see above on `vc.moc` in `prepareForSegue` which is clearly saying the view controller that conforms to the Dismassable protocol doesn't have a property called `moc` and that's true:

```
protocol Dismissable: class {
    weak var dismissalDelegate: DismissalDelegateProtocol? { get set }
    }
```

but shouldn't I be able to access a property of the view controller itself without making it part of the protocol?

I've search SO for quite a while and combed through [Apple's Protocol documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID267) but I haven't found an answer. I thought I was getting a good handle on protocols but it seems I'm still missing a key concept or two.

Comment: In your protocol you have `dismissalDelegate` but you are trying to set the `moc` which is part of your view controller. May be you need to cast the view controller to `SettingsViewController` instead of `Dismissible`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler knows only what you tell it. You say:

```
let vc = nav.topViewController as! Dismissable
```

Now `vc` is a Dismissable and that is *all* the compiler knows. And a Dismissable has no `moc` property. So when you try to talk about a Dismissable's `moc` property, the compiler stops you in your tracks.

But a SettingsViewController *does* have a `moc` property, as you rightly point out yourself. So tell the compiler that this *is* a SettingsViewController, if that is what it is:

```
if let svc = vc as? SettingsViewController {
    svc.moc = context
}
```

But think some more. Since SettingsViewController *is* a Dismissable, *and the compiler knows this*, that is in fact the *only* cast you need, since now you can also access the Dismissable properties. Hence your code can be completely rewritten:

```
    if let nav = segue.destinationViewController as? UINavigationController {
      if let vc = nav.topViewController as? SettingsViewController {
        vc.dismissalDelegate = self // fine, because a SVC is a Dismissable
        let context = viewModel.model.context
        vc.moc = context // fine, because a SVC is a SVC :)
      } 
    }
```

In other words, look at it this way: The compiler knows that a SettingsViewController is a Dismissable. But no law says that every Dismissable is a SettingsViewController. Your original code had the relationship backwards, that's all.

Comment: And notice my use of `if let ... as?`. Always a good idea, since `as!` can crash you. Not essential, but a good habit to get into.

Comment: Thanks for that thoughtful answer and bonus tips, @matt.